# How can I do the join between two queries, not get duplicate rows and make it compatible with looker studio?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to create a visualization in looker studio based on a BQ query. The query looks like follows:

```
agg as (
  select * from
  quotes 
  inner join budgets using(id,store,month)
  inner join sales using(id,store,month)
  inner join payments using(id,store,month)
  inner join specs using(id)
),t1 as (
  select worker_spec,
  worker_name,
  store,
  payment,
  quotes,
  sales,
  total_budget
  from agg
),t2 as (
  select worker_spec,
  store,
  sum(payment) as all_payments,
  sum(quotes) as all_quotes,
  sum(sales) as all_sales,
  sum(total_budget) as all_total_budget
  from agg
  group by worker_spec,store
)
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is this:

| store | worker_spec | all_payments | all_quotes | all_sales | all_total_budget | worker_name | payment | quotes | sales | total_budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store_1 | spec_1 | 123 | 240 | 19357991 | 42775873 | "john, doe" | 23 | 48 | 2741950 | 5837899 |
| store_2 | spec_1 | 20 | 32 | 4013910 | 9045256 | "john, doe" | 20 | 32 | 4013910 | 9045256 |
| store_3 | spec_1 | 104 | 211 | 15828317 | 40646381 |  |  |  |  |  |

Soo basically, I'm trying to get in the same table all fields by store and spec, and if a worker doesn't work in a specific store, just get null values for that row.

I manage to get this output by completing the query above this way:

```
select * from (
  select * from t2
  where worker_spec = (
    select distinct worker_specfrom t1
    where worker_name = 'john, doe'
)
)
left join (
  select * from t1
  where worker_name = 'john, doe'
) using(store,worker_spec)
```

But this can't be used in Looker Studio (or Data Studio), because I need to set the worker's name dynamically. I also tried to use parameters in Looker studio, but I can't find a way to populate the parameter by using data from source (in case the number of names change or a worker does not work there anymore).

On the other side, completing the query above by just doing a join between t1 and t2 gives me this kind of output:

```
select * from t2
right join t1 using(worker_spec)
where worker_name = 'john, doe'
```

| store | worker_spec | all_payments | all_quotes | all_sales | all_total_budget | worker_name | payment | quotes | sales | total_budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store_1 | spec_1 | 123 | 240 | 19357991 | 42775873 | "john, doe" | 23 | 48 | 2741950 | 5837899 |
| store_2 | spec_1 | 20 | 32 | 4013910 | 9045256 | "john, doe" | 23 | 48 | 2741950 | 5837899 |
| store_3 | spec_1 | 104 | 211 | 15828317 | 40646381 | "john, doe" | 23 | 48 | 2741950 | 5837899 |
| store_1 | spec_1 | 123 | 240 | 19357991 | 42775873 | "john, doe" | 20 | 32 | 4013910 | 9045256 |
| store_2 | spec_1 | 20 | 32 | 4013910 | 9045256 | "john, doe" | 20 | 32 | 4013910 | 9045256 |
| store_3 | spec_1 | 104 | 211 | 15828317 | 40646381 | "john, doe" | 20 | 32 | 4013910 | 9045256 |

Which has double the amount of rows required.

How can I achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result dynamically without hardcoding the worker's name in the query, you can modify the query using subqueries.

```
WITH
  agg AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM quotes
    INNER JOIN budgets USING (id, store, month)
    INNER JOIN sales USING (id, store, month)
    INNER JOIN payments USING (id, store, month)
    INNER JOIN specs USING (id)
  ),
  t1 AS (
    SELECT
      worker_spec,
      worker_name,
      store,
      payment,
      quotes,
      sales,
      total_budget
    FROM agg
  ),
  t2 AS (
    SELECT
      worker_spec,
      store,
      SUM(payment) AS all_payments,
      SUM(quotes) AS all_quotes,
      SUM(sales) AS all_sales,
      SUM(total_budget) AS all_total_budget
    FROM agg
    GROUP BY worker_spec, store
  ),
  worker_filter AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT worker_name
    FROM t1
  )
SELECT
  t2.store,
  t2.worker_spec,
  t2.all_payments,
  t2.all_quotes,
  t2.all_sales,
  t2.all_total_budget,
  t1.worker_name,
  t1.payment,
  t1.quotes,
  t1.sales,
  t1.total_budget
FROM t2
CROSS JOIN worker_filter
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.store = t1.store
  AND t2.worker_spec = t1.worker_spec
  AND t1.worker_name = worker_filter.worker_name;
```